# What software is used for maps of the US (or other arbitrary areas)?

Tags: data-visualization

What software does one use to create a map that describes conditions over an arbitrary area ? The example I am thinking of would be a map of the US where states that voted one way or another would be red or blue. Obviously I can get a map of the US and use a graphics program to manually paint in the states, but I am figuring there should be some sort of software to do that in a somewhat automated fashion. Apart from a for-pay web app, I haven't been able to find anything. I am very new to the field so I'm not familiar with the available tools.

Comment: You might be better off asking on http://gis.stackexchange.com .

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geographic_information_systems_software

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I need to go out ans look at these various options.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to the package that @robin pointed too, you should look at the [Spatial](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) Task View on CRAN. What you are describing is known as a [choropleth map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map), as illustrated here: [Choropleth Maps of Presidential Voting](http://www.r-bloggers.com/choropleth-maps-of-presidential-voting/), or [U.S. Unemployment Data: Animated Choropleth Maps](http://www.r-bloggers.com/u-s-unemployment-data-animated-choropleth-maps/).

In R, they can be handled using

- the base graphics routines (with [maps](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/index.html)),
- the lattice way (see `mapplot()` in [latticeExtra](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latticeExtra/index.html)),
- the ggplot2 way (see e.g., [Choropleth Challenge Results](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-challenge-result.html) for example code).

Other softwares that allow to deal with geographical maps include [Mondrian](http://rosuda.org/mondrian/Mondrian.html), [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) (and I guess many other GIS programs), but data format may vary from one software to the other.

Comment: +1 I also recommend Quantum GIS from the freely available, opensource softwares.

Answer (score 3):

You should try R software with package [spdep](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/index.html). see the vignette [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/vignettes/sids.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Self promotion: [JMP](http://www.jmp.com) (commercial desktop software) does choropleths of US states, US counties, world countries and regions of select other countries.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried [CrackMaps](http://www.crack4mac.com/) but it looks very interesting. Only available for the Mac, I presume.

Comment: (+1) Nice catch! It is limited to the US, isn't it?